# IPA file distribute ad hoc - Unable to install app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcode11

I'm trying to distribute my application for user testing but when the users installs the app and try run it they get an "Unable to install appname" error.

I have built and distributed the app using Xcode and Ad Hoc option. I have the IPA file saved on my drive. I have tried two options to have the app installed on another device in my office.

1) Provide the IPA file to my team member and they tried to open it with iTunes with iPhone connected. It flashes as if the file installed but they do not see their App option in the sidebar to see the apps installed on the iPhone. WHen I open iTunes and select my iPhone, I also do not see the Application menu in the sidebar.

2) I loaded my IPA file using www.diawi.com. I sent the link to my team member who managed to install the app on their iPhone. When they try to launch the app they get the "Unable to install appname" error. If I delete the app created by Xcode and use the Diawi link, the app run perfectly on my iPhone.

The app is built to iOS 12.4. My phone is a iPhone XR with iOS 13.1.2 and my team member is on a iPhone 8 iOS 13.1.2

How do I get IPA files onto different devices and how do I ensure they are able to launch?

Comment: Did you try installing it through XCode? Does your team member have XCode installed on his laptop?

Comment: No, I haven't done that because my client is on PC with iPhones and trying to simulate the same.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky and could not find the right info, had to ask a fellow developer.

•   Web browser
•   Go to Apple dev account
•   Go to Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles
•   Add devices with UDID under the Device section
•   Create a profile
•   Go to Xcode
•   Under app setting, Signing and Capabilities
•   Untick Automatically Manage Signing 
•   Select provisioning profile
•   Publish app and distribute to the phones you have setup